# Error loading txt files to synedit

Tags: delphi, synedit

I'm trying to load the text from a text file to a synmemo by using

```
procedure TForm1.btn7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if dlgOpen1.Execute then
    synm1.Lines.LoadFromFile(dlgOpen1.Files.Text);
end;
```

But as soon as I select a file i get this error:

> Cannot open file "C:\Users\adria\Desktop\New Text Document.txt
>   ". The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Component: https://github.com/TurboPack/SynEdit

Comment: Looks like that file does not exist .........

Comment: Does the file exist, or are you trying to create a new one? It doesn't matter here but you should really be using dlgOpen1.FileName to open the selected file. dlgOpen1.Files is designed to handle a number of files, not just one.

Comment: Does the `Files.Text` property contain the value you think it does? Use your debugging skills to inspect its value and confirm that your program is behaving the way you expect it to.

Comment: thx to @Dsm I used dlgOpen1.FileName instead

Comment: The real lesson here though is nothing to do with the specifics, but can be found in @Rob's comment. The single most common solution for questions asked here is for the asker to improve their debugging skills.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, please be careful when replacing images with text. In this case, your text conversion concealed a clue about the actual problem.

Comment: Precisely, @John. Thanks!

Comment: For crying out loud, if every question that could be answered by the vague directive that the OP should "improve their debugging skills" was removed from StackOverflow there wouldn't be much left.

Comment: @Deltics If people worked harder to learn how to debug, they'd be able to solve more problems themselves. Or do you think that debugging is not an important skill? You think it's better to do the fishing rather than teach how to fish. And what are you talking about with regards "removed"? Who said anything about removal? I honestly don't think you understand this site at all. If you don't like how the site works, bring it up on meta. Or go somewhere else that better fits your needs. Alternatively, stay here, learn how the site works, and continue writing excellent answers!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the use of the **Files** property of the dialog to access the selected filename.

The `Files` property is a *list* of strings intended for use when you have enabled multiple selection in the dialog and need to process more than one filename selected by the user.

The `Text` property of string list returns a formatted representation of all entries in that list with each entry delimited by an **EOL** character (or characters).

You might expect that where only a single file is involved that this `Text`property would contain only the name of that file.  But in fact it also includes an **EOL** character.  i.e. the filename you are trying to open by using this technique is actually:

```
'C:\Users\adria\Desktop\New Text Document.txt'#13#10
```

There was actually a clue to this in the way that the message was being displayed, with the closing quotes on a separate line as a result of that **EOL**.

The correct way to work with the selected filename depends on whether you are supporting multiple selection or single.

In the case of *single* selection (your case here) the simplest approach is to use the `Filename` property of the dialog:

```
if dlgOpen1.Execute then
  synm1.Lines.LoadFromFile(dlgOpen1.Filename);
```

For *multiple* selection you would use the `Files` property, but access each filename by index in the list:

```
if dlgOpen1.Execute then
  for i := 0 to Pred(dlgOpen1.Files.Count) do
  begin
    // Do something with each dlgOpen1.Files[i] ...
  end;
```